# E/ExternalAccountType﹕ Unsupported attribute readOnly

Tags: android

In android when i am creating directory in sdCard this error displaying.please help me how to solve this problem.

```
package com.example.aaaaa; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import java.io.File;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mnt/sdcard/mydir/"); 
        mydir.mkdir();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: package com.example.aaaaa;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mnt/sdcard/mydir/");

        mydir.mkdir();



    }



}

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory, you could use

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dirName");

if(!myDirectory.exists()) {                                 
  myDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

dont forget to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: dont give the directory name like this /mnt/sdcard/mydir/.. give it just 'mydirectory'  and check if its works or not